# Java bean validation - override default message

Tags: java, bean-validation

How can I return different messages on a class level validator?

**Interface**

```
public @interface ValidFoo
{
    public String message() default "{package.ValidFoo.message}";
}
```

**Implementation**

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(final Foo foo, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
{
    // check constraint 1
    // --> return message "package.ValidFoo.message_constraint1"

    // check constraint 2
    // --> return message "package.ValidFoo.message_constraint2"
}
```

**ValidationMessages.properties**

```
package.ValidFoo.message=Validation error.
package.ValidFoo.message_constraint1=Validation error 1.
package.ValidFoo.message_constraint2=Validation error 2.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the *ConstraintValidatorContext* to select the right message template. You can see an example in the Hibernate Validator docs - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-validator.

Effectively you do something like:

```
    constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
            "{package.ValidFoo.message_constraint1}" 
    )
    .addConstraintViolation();
```

Comment: Do you also know if it is possible to add an message attribute for formatting at runtime (`"{0}"` )? It seems only hardcoded attributes in the interface definition can be used, and those cannot be updated.

Comment: In Bean Validation 1.0 only static variables were allowed. Hibernate Validator also allows for interpolating the validated value itself. This made it also into the Bean Validation 1.1 specification update. This does not allow for adding any dynamic variables though. We might implement something like this in Hibernate Validator soon - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-701. Feel free to leave a comment on the issue to describe your usecase.

Comment: In many class-level constraint this feature is helpful since the validation can depend on dynamic properties. Another usecase is a simple credential check. For example `Order in state {0} cannot be updated by client of type {1}.` In this case the type must also be passed to the validator instance somehow unless it is a property of Order itself which seems a bad workaround. So I must validate this case manually to create the correct message or use a generic message. `Invalid credentials to update Order in current state.`.